# MLModel style transfer prediction. Scale effect(brushstrokes)

Tags: swift, pytorch, mlmodel, style-transfer

I have style transfer model which is trained by `pytorch` and converted by onnx to `mlmodel`. The `style-image` was `1500x2000`. By using `coremltools` I set two sizes: `256x256` and `1500x2000`.
Now I can pass two image sizes to prediction process. Here are results:
[image]

On the left side it is `1500x2000` image, and on the right side is `256x256` (scaled up after processing)
Is it possible to pass big image but have bigger size of brushstrokes as you can see on image on the right? So I want to keep image size and quality (`1500x2000`) but change the size of style(brushstrokes). Or it is not possible and it is totally depend of `image-style` size I was using to train model.